# How can I get the aws partition from CodeBuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

CodeBuild has some environment variables(eg. CODEBUILD_NUMBER, AWS_REGION, etc) that are readily accessible from the container. Is there an environment variable to get the aws partition (eg. aws, aws-cn, aws-us-gov, etc)

Comment: Could you extract the partition from `CODEBUILD_BUILD_ARN`?

Comment: You should definitely be able to extract that from the `AWS_REGION`.

Comment: I can but I was wondering if there is something built-in(eg. AWS_PARTITION) since the AWS_REGION is already available.

Comment: There is nothing built-in. There is no `AWS_PARTITION` environment variable or anything like that. You have to extract it from the current region or an ARN.